# Chrome extension messages not getting through

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

**manifest.json:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "chrome-extension-bar",
  "description": "Chrome Extension Bar",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Chrome Extension Bar",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "tabs"
  ],

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com/ https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com ; object-src 'self'"
}
```

**background.js:**

```
console.log("In background.js")
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener (
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log("In listener");
        // to send back your response  to the current tab
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {fileData: response}, function(response) {
                sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
            });
        });

        return true;
    }
);
```

**content_script.js:**

```
var current_title_bar = document.getElementById("global-nav");
console.log("Title bar:" + current_title_bar);
current_title_bar.appendChild(extension_bar); // <= GODD, getting here

document.getElementById("idStartButton").addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('Sending start button message: ' + document.getElementById("idNumSecondsPerPage").value);
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({numSecondsPerPage : document.getElementById("idNumSecondsPerPage").value}, function(response) {
        console.log('Got response: ' + response.farewell);
      });
});

document.getElementById("idStopButton").addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('Sending stop button message: ' + document.getElementById("idNumPages").value);
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({numPages : document.getElementById("idNumPages").value}, function(response) {
        console.log('Got response: ' + response.farewell);
      });
});
```

The messages seem to be getting sent, but there's I'm not getting anything back from the receiver.

Console log on the page into which the form was injected:

```
Entering content_script.js
content_script.js:156 Title bar:[object HTMLElement]
content_script:161 Sending start button message: 67
content_script:168 Sending stop button message: 76
```

Why aren't the messages sent by background.js received by content_script.js? Are they even sent?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send a message from the `background.js` script to the `content_script.js` then you need to set an onMessage listener on the content script.

What you might do in this case is, after receiving the event on the **background script**, just call the callback function, instead you're sending a new event with a callback function than when it is executed, calls the callback function of the first event.

Instead of doing this:

```
console.log("In listener");
// to send back your response  to the current tab
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {fileData: response}, function(response) {
        sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    });
});
```

just do this

```
console.log("In listener");
// send back your response
sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
```

Comment: The background scripts sends a response only after receiving something from the content script. Changing the contents of background.js to sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"}); still doesn't send anything to content_script.js

Comment: I'm not sure of what you wanted to say here. When the background script actually receives the message from the content, it should just call **sendResponse** callback which is the function passed to the event, that logs "Got response ..." to answer (in this case with `{farewell: "goodbye"}`). Isn't that what you want to do? That way, the background answers when the message is sent (AKA the button is clicked). Note that I told you to replace **a part** of the `background.js`, not all of it.

Comment: Managed to get it to run (will update question tomorrow)